# Spring Boot groovyファイル実行でエラー　Log4j2 ？

Tags: spring, groovy

以下から「Spring Boot CLI」というソフトウェアをダウンロードしました。
[10.2 Installing the Spring Boot CLI | Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-installing-the-cli)

環境変数を追加しました。
C:\Users\yoshi\Desktop\spring-2.0.2.RELEASE\bin

以下のファイルをデスクトップに置きました。

ファイル名：app.groovy

```java
@RestController
class App {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  def home() {
    "Hello!"
  }
}
```

コマンドプロンプトで「spring run app.groovy」と打ちました。

以下のエラーが出ました。どうすればよいでしょうか。

```
C:\Users\yoshi>cd desktop

C:\Users\yoshi\Desktop>spring run app.groovy
Resolving dependencies....
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::  (v2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

ERROR DefaultListableBeanFactory Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6c84aed8: startup date [Thu May 24 01:53:30 JST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:420)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:95)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:240)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:576)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:552)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:227)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1035)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:562)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.app.SpringApplicationLauncher.launch(SpringApplicationLauncher.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner$RunThread.run(SpringApplicationRunner.java:173)
ERROR SpringApplication Application run failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ClockProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:203)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:709)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.app.SpringApplicationLauncher.launch(SpringApplicationLauncher.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner$RunThread.run(SpringApplicationRunner.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ClockProvider
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:33)
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
        at org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory.getObject(MessageInterpolatorFactory.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator$Delegate.<init>(ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.java:71)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.<init>(ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.java:43)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.getIfJsr303Present(ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.<init>(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:78)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1763)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1700)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ClockProvider
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.ExtendedGroovyClassLoader.findClass(ExtendedGroovyClassLoader.java:84)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:678)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:788)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:776)
        ... 29 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.app.SpringApplicationLauncher.launch(SpringApplicationLauncher.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner$RunThread.run(SpringApplicationRunner.java:173)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ClockProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:203)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:709)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ClockProvider
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:33)
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:276)
        at org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory.getObject(MessageInterpolatorFactory.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator$Delegate.<init>(ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.java:71)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.<init>(ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.java:43)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.getIfJsr303Present(ConfigurationPropertiesJsr303Validator.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.<init>(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:69)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:78)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1763)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1700)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ClockProvider
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.ExtendedGroovyClassLoader.findClass(ExtendedGroovyClassLoader.java:84)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:678)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:788)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:776)
        ... 29 more
C:\Users\yoshi\Desktop>
```

Comment: `C:\Users\yoshi\Desktop\spring-2.0.2.RELEASE\bin`とログの`:: Spring Boot ::  (v2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)`のバージョンが違うのが気になりますね。複数のバージョンを使用していますか？

Comment: [少し古い投稿ですが](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6523#issuecomment-238024384)、ローカルMavenリポジトリをクリーンアップした( `~/.m2/repository` ディレクトリを削除した)ら問題が解消した、というものがありますね。

Comment: ありがとうございます！確認したところデスクトップに「spring-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT」という別のフォルダがあり、それをデスクトップから排除したら動くようになりました！　表示されているバージョンの違いに気づきませんでした。ありがとうございました。